# IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [AdminController] and [muShag.Private.controller.AdminController] are both mapped to the url-pattern

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, servlets, mapping

I created an application in JAVA 7 with Tomcat 7 in Eclipse Juno.It was running perfectly at that time but after some days it stopped working. now whenever i am trying to run that application it shows error as:

> ```
> SEVERE: A child container failed during start java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> ```
>
> org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/MuShag]]
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/MuShag]]
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
>     ... 7 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The
>   servlets named [AdminController] and
>   [muShag.Private.controller.AdminController] are both mapped to the
>   url-pattern [/AdminController] which is not permitted     at
>   org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.addServletMapping(WebXml.java:335)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationWebServlet(ContextConfig.java:2412)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2125)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2080)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2073)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2073)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2073)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1300)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:369)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5179)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 7 more 26 Jul, 2013 9:36:50 PM

Now how can handle these errors. after surfing too much at some place i got a way by adding commons-looging.jar, but it doesnot worked.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The error message says it all:

> The servlets named [AdminController] and [muShag.Private.controller.AdminController] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/AdminController] which is not permitted.

Fix your web.xml or your annotations so that those two servlets are not mapped to the same url-pattern, or so that only one of those servlets is defined.

Comment: It's more likely that the OP has used annotations in his code and lost track of his URL mappings. Hooray for annotations!

Comment: Indeed. Added "or your annotations" to the answer.